# Generate pdf laravel 9 with class css

Tags: laravel

I would like to generate a pdf of the graphs in this view in Laravel I have inserted a dropdown with individual layouts I would like to use the CSS classes to divide the graphs and create layouts but I don't know where I'm going wrong this is the view with the graphs in photo and this is the code thank you very much I hope someone can help me..

[image]

[image]

````
     /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function generatePDF(Request $request)

    {
      // Class
      $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
      // View
      $pdf->loadHTML('dashboard-pers');
      return $pdf->stream();
    }```
````

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, please explain it more clearly.